# Fail during cloning/pushing: git/info/refs not valid: could not determine hash algorithm; is this a git repository?

Tags: git

Every time i try to use git bash on my windows computer and try to update a repository this message shows up after each git push or git clone even if the repository is correct and there is the file .git; I tried to reinstall the software but still the problem persist and it makes impossible to use git properly. Also this problem showed up one day without change any settings or using git at all

I tried to uninstall and reinstall software. I tried to put my account info (username and email from github) into the global settings again and still doesnt work

Comment: You'll need to provide more information, but I will note that this is the *kind* of corruption that sometimes shows up if you attempt to store a Git repository in a cloud-synced folder such as Dropbox or iCloud. Things seem to work for a while and then the Git repository is mysteriously corrupted. The corruption occurs because cloud syncing software assumes that a human, not a computer, is using the files.

Answer (score -1):

If working with a remote server, try using the SSH protocol instead of HTTPS.
and check if you have permission to access this repo

Comment: I don’t think this answers the question.